# Remove elements by className

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have found posts that suggest a solution to how to remove an element: first, `getElementById()`, then use `.remove()` method.

Suppose I have many elements that belong to a class `className`. I have to do a `for` loop to get each id in order to remove them all.
Is there a faster way to apply `remove()` on a `className`? I have tried the below code and it does not work (i.e. all the elements do not get deleted).

```
let elementGrp = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class-name');
elementGrp.remove();
```

Comment: No, you'll have to remove each element in the collection individually. `.remove()` can only be called on elements, not collections.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for confirming. Closing this then.